# Как сделать Slideshow в telegram instant view?

Tags: api, telegram, xpath

Если кто то из сообщества stackoverflow участвует в конкурсе от telegram, instant view

Как вывести Slideshow? В документации вообще не какой информации толком нету
https://instantview.telegram.org/docs

Буду очень благодарен!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вообще это нужно под конкретно ваш слайдер настраивать. У меня вот такой код:
Чтобы извлечь изображение из слайдера, отобразите его и добавьте в тело

```
$slide: //a[has-class("rsImg")] // ваш класс
@set_attr(src, @href): $slide
<img>: $slide
@wrap(<figure>): $@
@append_to($body): $@
@append(<slideshow>): $body
@append_to(//slideshow): $body//figure
```